# The GDB process terminated

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, gdb, qt-creator

I've used Qt Creator to create my own Qt project, which has been available to serial port.

However, when I tried to debug my project, it always displays the following message, especially when there were breaks in my projects:

> Error:  The GDB process teminated.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There can be different reasons, with different solutions;

> (Below will list those most commonly causing this for me.)

### #1 Toolchain

It's maybe related to your toolchain, for example I experienced similar issues, where I was compiling my code with latest MingW, but Qt was built with a little older MingW compiler.

> I searched everywhere for the specific MingW, that which Qt was built with, but could not find that.
>
> The only solution for me was to rebuild Qt from scratch (and fix all build errors).

### #2 Permission

Another time, I was trying to attach debugger to an App running as root.

After running IDE (and by that the debugger) as root, things started to work.

> But sometimes, following below `#3` was required, too.

### #3 Working Directory

Apps may load dependencies based on current-working-directory, for this case:

If you want to attach-debugger to already running root App:

- We need to change the way IDE is launched, for example, open the terminal and `cd` to where the App requires us to (like directory containing the executable), then launch IDE from terminal (using it's path).

  > <sup>This may only be required when attaching to App(s) running as root, and even there not for all IDEs (but was required for QtCreator v4.x at least).</sup>

If you don't attach:

- Simply change IDE configurations, I mean, most IDEs allow you to select working-directory (like QtCreator does), first do that and then start debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Some MinGW GDB versions will crash on `info registers` command.

[BugID SRC](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/731/)

[BugID](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26304)

Once a debugger panel in Qt Creator opened, it will keep sending `info registers` command to GDB.

To stop this, remove `Debugger.MainWindow/ChangedDocks` and `Debugger.MainWindow/State` fields from `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\QtCreator.ini`

```
[Debugger.MainWindow]
AutoHideTitleBars=true
ShowCentralWidget=true

ChangedDocks=[REMOVED THIS]
State=[REMOVE THIS]
```

> You Can completely remove the whole line instead.